# regex for validation Data

Tags: java, validation

i am a beginner in regular expression and i need a help after ours searching i didn't find a solution in web.

i need a regular expression for validation Data of this form only `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MMMMM` example `2016-12-10 10:38:56.567000`

Comment: Why use regex when you can use `Date` objects ?

Comment: yes you are write i use regex for validation different fields and help me, less code,i tried the tow examples but dosent works so i with contine with Data obj.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers.  The first one does simple check

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6}
```

But it would let in false positives such as `2016-13-10 10:38:56.567000` (invalid month of `13`).  To prevent these false positives, your regex needs to be more precise and would have to be something like this (I worked only on the year and month, but you have to work through all other fields too)

```
(20|19)\d{2}-(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|11|12)-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6}
```